# CSS for triggering Avada toggles using an image or clickable element

Tags: themes, support

I'm looking for a CSS code for triggering Avada toggles using an element other than the toggle’s own button?

I just want to be able to open and close a series of toggles with my own custom buttons. That means I need a CSS class to apply to my element (for which there is already a section available) and then a corresponding code with a matching signature (i.e “button1″,”button2” etc) to apply to the toggle so it will open/close when prompted. I'm not sure where I would apply it to Avada's toggles - it may need to go into the actual page code - but there is an in-built box for HTML.

I've only done a little coding, so I appreciate the help!